# Error while creating a react app using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The error in the image shows up while creating a react app .
It was working properly all this time, all i did was mkdir and cd to that dir.

This is what the error looks like...

*npx: installed 99 in 36.634s
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\5172\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\5172\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\5172\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file 
as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\5172\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Neeraj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\5172\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to downgrade version of node to 12.11.1

`$ npm install -g n
$ n 12.12.0`

Comment: I tried reinstalling to version 12.12.0 and now its working.  Thank you. PS: The command did not work. Mayb due to a windows system. I reinstalled from nodejs website.

Answer (score 3):

This was related to is-promise library https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/13. Please don't downgrade the node version. They have released new version https://github.com/then/is-promise/releases/tag/2.2.1 which will fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

run this command :

```
npm install is-promise@2.1.0 --save --save-exact
```

or, if you just want to create react app, you can do this while waiting for a fix:
step 1: yarn init -y

step 2: Insert this to package.json

"resolutions": {
    "is-promise": "2.1.0",
    "run-async/is-promise": "2.1.0"
  }

step 3: yarn add --dev create-react-app

step 4: yarn create-react-app ../my-app